# Edit reply on Careers?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I've clicked "interested" on a message and now I can't edit my reply. The problem is that the employer linked to a website and there's no obvious way to contact them.

I would like to have a way to edit my "No response text" reply.

Comment: We are currently looking into this request.  Right now when you reply with interest, your contact info is emailed to the employer, so they should be able to get in touch with you.  In addition to this we will also look into ways to make who is waiting for what more clear at this point in the process.

Comment: Thanks, @NickLarsen. Great to hear!

Comment: @NickLarsen - It seems that this has been at least partially fulfilled. Would you care to retag as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of June 2011, this seems to have been fulfilled at least partially.

Comment: Aye, we decided to make the messages threaded instead of allowing edits.